# How to exclude pdb files when deploying to Service Fabric?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

When deploying multiple services to Service Fabric from Visual Studio 2015 in release mode, each of them seem to contain a lot of pdb files from either my own assemblies as well as 3rd party (AWSSDK.pdb is over 40 MB!).

How to exclude these when deploying to Service Fabric?

Comment: This would be good to know for deterministic builds.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working. I used the out-of-the-box service fabric application build definition. Find the step called package solution - I believe it's the third step in the build process. In any case, it's the step where msbuild packages up the service fabric project (sfproj).

I added the following msbuild parameters:

`/p:DebugType=none /p:DebugSymbols=false`

The full msbuild argument list should end up looking like this:

`/t:Package /p:PackageLocation=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\applicationpackage /p:DebugType=none /p:DebugSymbols=false`

Voila! No PDBs. :)